# PHP does not store strings in $_SESSION

Tags: php, session

I have weird problem where I'm storing some data in the `$_SESSION` variable. The problem lies between line 8 and 9. Somehow data is not stored in the session. And I'm clueless where the problem can lie.

When assigning the `$data` variable to session, it works, but when assining something from `$data` to session it doesn't work! But the line 7 shows me that accessing the `$data` array works.

Where is the problem?

Here [link](http://pastebin.com/AcUGBgLM) is an example of `print_r($_SESSION)`

code:

```
 1: $ldap = new adLDAP();
 2: $ldap->authenticate($username, $password);
 3: $ldapUser = $ldap->user();
 4: $data = $ldapUser->info($username, $this->ldapInfo);
 5: $managerArr = explode(',', $data[0]['manager'][0]);
 6: $managerCN = explode('=', $managerArr[0]);
 7: $this->log->debug("Display Name = " . $data[0]['displayname'][0]);
 8: //$_SESSION['ldap_raw'] = $data; // <--- this freakin works
 9: $_SESSION[UserDetails::sessionInfoName][UserDetails::sessionInfoTitleName] = $data[0]['title'][0];
10: $_SESSION[UserDetails::sessionInfoName][UserDetails::sessionInfoTelephoneNumber] = $data[0]['telephonenumber'][0];
11: $_SESSION[UserDetails::sessionInfoName][UserDetails::sessionInfoDisplayNameName] = $data[0]['displayname'][0]);
```

`UserDetails::sessionInfoName` and `UserDetails::sessionInfoXXXXYYYY` are constants defined in the class UserDetails

Comment: place `print_r($data); die;` before line 9 and tell us what you see

Comment: Usually session is an array...  You can't use it like that

Comment: Please provide `UserDetails::sessionInfo*` and `$data` most likely you're referencing array keys that don't exist (and ignoring the notices).

Comment: @AvnerSolomon why do you say that?

Comment: Try `$_SESSION[UserDetails::sessionInfoName] = array()` first

Comment: @jcubic, you're not at "Stackoverflow: the Question and Guesses website"

Comment: @AvnerSolomon What one earth do you mean!!?? The is a one of several methods you can set a value in an array and as `$_SESSION` is an array, of course you can use it like that!

Comment: I meant if u don't  say on some servers $a[x]  = array()  first,  a[x] [y]  won't work....  Sorry I'm on phone...

Comment: @AvnerSolomon you should practice a bit more with PHP arrays, sorry.

Comment: @STTLCU .. no mate. You should know that you can not access indices of uninitialized data structures, sorry.

Comment: @AvnerSolomon In Java, C++ and the like you'd be correct. but in PHP a call like `$arr['not_exists']['completely_invented']['foo']['bar']['idontexist'] = 1` is perfectly correct and will initialize the correct structure in your array.

Comment: @STTLCU ... that's what I'm saying , depdending on server( actually on PHP settings) that will or will not work like that.

Comment: You're wrong, period. Anyway, this is not the place to discuss such matters.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is obviously NOT to do with `session_start()` as you have clearly stated that it works when you explicitly set the array key.

You must follow the following steps to determine what the issue is:

1. Print the `UserDetails` object and ensure the values you are retrieving are set AND also ensure they are `public`.
2. Print `$data` to ensure that you have the right levels set in your array. For instance, you are referencing `$data[0]['title'][0]`, this might actually be `$data[0]['title']`.

This is likely to just be a minor error in the variables/objects you are referencing as there is nothing syntactically incorrect with your code, therefore printing this data should reveal what the issue is!

Do the following:

```
$ldap = new adLDAP();
$ldap->authenticate($username, $password);
$ldapUser = $ldap->user();
$data = $ldapUser->info($username, $this->ldapInfo);
$managerArr = explode(',', $data[0]['manager'][0]);
$managerCN = explode('=', $managerArr[0]);
$this->log->debug("Display Name = " . $data[0]['displayname'][0]);

// Print the $data array
print_r($data);

// Print the UserDetails object instance
print_r(UserDetails);

exit;
```